# nsuserdefaults in viewdidload disable hidding views

Tags: swift, boolean, nsuserdefaults

I'm using nsuserdefaults to save some bools data but I'm facing problem: 
in my storyboard, I checked 'hidden' for a view, but when I use my application, the view is not 'hidden' and i noticed it's because my userdefaults in the `viewdidload:` when i delete it, the view is hidden.
Is there a way to set it hidden?
i tried in `viedidload` to set hidden but don't work.
here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // viewnote2.hidden = true
     let boolsKey = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
     viewnote2.hidden = boolsKey.boolForKey("bool2")
 }
```

that's all about this view

Comment: Where and how do you save the value for `bool2`?

Comment: i save it when i touch a button. it don't change the bool value  obviously

Comment: You should save the bool as described in NDoc's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time change on `UI` doesn't work on `viewDidLoad`, try to hide the view on `viewDidAppear`. Also check that you have set the `Bool` value for `bool2` key in `UserDefaults`.

If you haven't set the Bool value in `UserDefaults` than you need to set first like this.

```
let boolsKey = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
boolsKey.setBool(false,forKey:"bool2")
boolsKey.synchronize()
```

**Edit:** For setting bool in `AppDelegate`.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {        
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let boolsKey = defaults.boolForKey("bool2")
    if boolsKey {
        defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "bool2")
        defaults.synchronize()
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: However , each time I launch my application , the view is hidden, even if I change the `bool` to `true`.
I don't know how can I set it just once in my `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Try to set that `false` in `AppDelgate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. that will help you. Also don't forgot to `synchronize` the `UserDefaults`.

Comment: thank you, but I'm a beginner .. I never used it.
If you wouldn't mind , can you give me a simple example?

Answer (score 1):

To add a value to boolsKey you use

```
boolsKey.setBool(value: Bool, forKey: String)
```

So for when the user checks 'hidden' for view the program should run

```
boolsKey.setBool(false, forKey: "bool2")
```

and after that you could read from it like you did

```
viewnote2.hidden = boolsKey.boolForKey("bool2")
```

Answer (score 0):

This like here:

```
boolsKey.boolForKey("bool2")
```

Is returning false, thus you can look at your `viewnote2` as being set like this:

```
viewnote2.hidden = false
```

The value that you're saving for `"bool2"` is obviously not correct.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much @NDoc! firstly I tried to hide on `viewDidAppear` but when I launch the application , we see the view 1 second before to be hidden. 
Then, I tried to set it in `NSUserdefault` on `viewDidLoad` with
                                                                                                                                                  `boolsKey.setBool(false,forKey:"bool2")`
`boolsKey.synchronize()`
like that:

```
    if (boolsKey.boolForKey("bool2") == true){

    boolsKey.setBool(true,forKey:"bool2")
    boolsKey.synchronize()
    } else {
        boolsKey.setBool(false,forKey:"bool2")
        boolsKey.synchronize()
    }
```

it work for me :-)